# Is it possible to lookup a js module in 2 different folders while priortizing one over the other?

Tags: webpack, build, es6-modules, gulp-webpack

I need to create a highly customizable webapp and wondered if and how it is possible to make use of es6 module loading in combination with webpack to override single files of a bigger app-stack.

So lets assume i have a directory structure like:

```
./src
|--/core
|--|--moduleA.js
|--|--moduleB.js
|--|--app.js
|--/theme
|--|--moduleB.js
```

and my app.js content is like

```
import moduleA from "./moduleA";
import moduleB from "./moduleB";

console.log(moduleA); // out: i am from core!
console.log(moduleB); // out: i am from theme!
```

So the theme/ directory simply overrides the core files...

Is there a way to solve this with webpack loader config or do i have to run a pre-build, in which i copy all files from core to a third location, followed by the same for the theme directory followed by a build from that third directory.

I know how to solve this with a third location and merged src files but i would prefer to solve this with webpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible with [resolve modules](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules).
You can add both `core` and `theme` as modules. Define `theme` first so webpack looks there first.

```
modules: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, "src/theme"),
    path.resolve(__dirname, "src/core"),
    'node_modules',
]
```

Then import the modules without the relative path. Just `from "moduleA"`

Comment: Yes, that works - thank you. Do you know how to configure my ide (jetbrains phpstorm) to understand that setup?

Comment: @PhilippWrann sorry I only use vim, but I found this, maybe that works https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17254